# Pgfgantt: table or formatting for the task names and extra information

Tags: pgfgantt

**Problem:** I am trying to include more information on the task name on a Gantt chart made with pgfgantt, in the form: ID, task name, duration and perhaps more information such as start/end dates. I am planning on making fortnightly and summary Gantt charts for specific periods so I need to include ID's so that they can be referenced.

**My current method:** I am using a custom command with `\parbox`'s so that the information can be included and spaced correctly but I could not see a way to include a heading above it to specify what the information means e.g. "ID", "Task Name", "Duration". Nor could I find a way to include formatting like boundaries so it resembles a table.

**What I would like:** Preferably, if there is a way to put information in a table to the left of the Gantt chart that would be ideal, but if that is not possible or difficult (I do not know TikZ well and I read that is what pgfgantt uses) then a way of introducing boundaries ("[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb9If.png) | Example task name | 3 days ") and/or a heading above the first entry would be nice. I am open to other methods then using `\parbox` but that is a back-up method if needed. I obtained most of the code in the MWE from the pgfgantt manual, I think it was an example.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\newcommand\TEF[3]{\textbf{[#1]}\hspace{0.2cm}\parbox{3cm}{#2}\hspace{0.2cm}\parbox{1cm}{#3}}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[ %
    vgrid, hgrid,
    y unit title=0.6cm,
    y unit chart=0.5cm,
    title label font=\tiny,
    bar label font=\tiny,
    group label font=\tiny,
    milestone label font=\tiny,
    today label font=\tiny,
    vrule label font=\tiny]{1}{24}
\gantttitle{2011}{24} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,24}{1} \\
\ganttgroup{\TEF{3}{Text to see if it puts it in right}{14 days}}{1}{7} \\
\ganttbar{\TEF{3}{Text to see if it puts it in right}{2 days}}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{\TEF{3}{Text to see if it puts it in right}{2 days}}{3}{7} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{\TEF{3}{Text to see if it puts it in right}{2 days}}{7} \ganttnewline
\ganttbar{\TEF{3}{Text to see if it puts it in}{2 days}}{8}{12}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}

\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

**How it currently looks:**

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, I am not sure why there is such a gap between the "# days" and the chart either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to style the `bar-`, `group-` and `milestone-` `label node` keys using `rectangle split` to make 3 columns. Then you can use a modified version of your `\TEF` command to place the content in each `nodepart`. Each of those `nodepart`s can then be formatted for the necessary width, alignment and so on. The column headers are just a `ganttbar` that does not draw a bar.

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/612214/
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\newcommand\TEF[3]{\nodepart[text width=0.75cm,align=center]{one}\textbf{[#1]} 
                   \nodepart[text width=3cm]{two}{#2} 
                   \nodepart[text width=1.0cm,align=right]{three}{#3}
                   }

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[ %
    vgrid, hgrid,
    y unit title=0.6cm,
    y unit chart=0.75cm,
    title label font=\tiny,
    bar label font=\tiny,
    bar label node/.append style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,rectangle split horizontal,draw,},
    group label font=\tiny,
    group label node/.append style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,rectangle split horizontal,draw},
    milestone label font=\tiny,
    milestone label node/.append style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,rectangle split horizontal,draw},
    today label font=\tiny,
    vrule label font=\tiny]{1}{12}
\gantttitle{2011}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttbar{\TEF {ID} {Task Name} {Duration}}{1} {0} \\
\ganttgroup{\TEF {1} {Text to see if it puts it in right} {14 days}} {1} {7} \\
\ganttbar{\TEF {2} {Text to see if it puts it in right} {2 days}} {1} {2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{\TEF {3} {Text to see if it puts it in right} {2 days}} {3} {7} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{\TEF {4} {Text to see if it puts it in right} {2 days}} {7} \ganttnewline
\ganttbar[bar/.append style={fill=green}]{\TEF {5} {Text to see if it puts it in} {2 days}} {8} {12}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem4}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Which gives this:
[image]